# Медлительность питона. Является ли это правдой?

Tags: python

Заинтересовался программированием 1,5 месяца назад, в качестве первого языка взял Python. Язык мне приглянулся, да еще и после того, как я прочитал, что на нем можно и игры на android/ios, и все остальное писать, решил, что полностью изучу его и все у меня будет хорошо) Но недавно прочитал пару статей, где было написано, что питон - один из самых медлительных языков. Я хотел бы делать игры под андроид/иос на питоне, но не знаю, является ли правдой то, что написали в статьях. Есть тут те, кто пишут игры на телефон на питоне? Отличаются ли они в быстродействии от игр, написанных на других языках? Стоит ли начинать учиться писать игры на питоне или лучше выбрать другой язык?
P.S. Еще прочитал, что JS - тоже универсальный язык и на нем тоже можно писать игры, так ли это? И если это так, то какой язык лучше в этом плане, JS или Python? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если вы планируете развиваться именно в направлении игр для смартфона, то лучше всё-таки учить Java (не JavaScript - это два разных языка). Что касается медлительности - то это не совсем так. Во-первых, даже если брать его сам по себе, то слухи об его медлительности сильно преувеличены. Во-вторых, тяжёлые вычисления на нём обычно не пишут с нуля, а используют библиотеки, в которых под капотом крутится c++, и это позволяет писать на питоне достаточно шустрые программы. Но всё-таки для смартфона он - не самый оптимальный выбор, и дело тут не в быстродействии.

Comment: @Александр про Java и JavaScript я знаю, я не настолько новичок) Не знаю, видели ли вы мой предыдущий вопрос, в котором я написал, что у меня тормозит 2д игра, написанная с помощью pygame, что вы думаете по этому поводу? Код у меня написан правильно, а игра тормозит. И еще, что вы думаете именно про JS и игры?

Comment: JS всё таки больше на веб ориентирован. Нужно создать и поддерживать сервер. И опять-таки, это не тот язык, который хорош для мобильных приложений. Но для десктопных игр в браузере именно js и используют.

Comment: А ваш предыдущий вопрос смогу посмотреть только через пару дней - сейчас с телефона сижу, с него неудобно заниматься профилированием кода )

Comment: @Александр понял, спасибо) мой код смотреть особо и не надо, он не запускается) я туда только функции скинул, потому что думал, что дело в них)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Про медлительность правда, питон и вправду медленный, по поводу игр: ничего вы на питоне не напишете, то есть теоретически можете попробовать, но даже простенький платформер будет труден в создании, если вы хотите писать игры под ios/android лучше всего использовать unity, чтоб писать игры на unity, используется язык C#, по нему есть куча уроков, больше о языке можете загуглить, так же на unity можно писать выше упомянутый JS, но в работе с ним для таких целей, у меня нет опыта, однако сам JS и вправду очень универсальный.
P.S. питон имеет смысл учить, если вы хотите писать сайты или вам интересны такие вещи как научные вычисления или нейросети

Comment: Создатель Unity, залогинься. JS давно не поддерживается в Unity, на Unreal Engine тоже можно писать игры под смартфоны, про отдельные фреймворки и библиотеки под джаву я даже не заикаюсь. Не вводите людей в заблуждение.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker ваше сообщение, конечно, было адресовано не мне, но мне было бы интересно узнать его смысл? вы говорите про то, что на питоне можно полноценно писать игры или вы про джаваскрипт?)

Comment: @ИльяРоманов, Unity - не единственный и уж тем более не самый производительный способ писать игры под андроид, возможно, самый удобный и быстрый в разработке способ. На JS в Unity уже не пишут, потому что Unity его больше не поддерживает, о чем я и указал.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker понял) этому вопросу вы не будете минус ставить?))

Comment: @ИльяРоманов, вы о чем?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker на моем вопросе, куда я скинул код функций, я так понял, вы минус поставили)

Comment: @ИльяРоманов, не стоит угадывать, кто именно поставил вам минус - с большой долей вероятности вы ошибетесь. Вообще лучше не заморачиваться по поводу репутации: репутация - дело наживное.

Comment: @ИльяРоманов, без понятия, кто и где вам поставил минус

Comment: @insolor да я не заморачиваюсь, просто интересно)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker ну ладно, значит совпадение) в любом случае, спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Ответ очень поверхностный, сплошное имхо

Comment: это как раз питон очень универсальный ), а хайповость js из-за развития веба. Не будь он основным языком в браузере, то реальность была бы иной.

Comment: вы не правы, js используется в QT, то есть для программирования под desktop, на нем же пишут прикладное ПО для приставок, так же (не знаю насколько правда) его используют для программирования терминалов оплаты и т.п.